# Is it always possible to choose an analytic parametrization near an elliptic point?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature, analytic-functions

I am reading the proof of a proposition in the textbook "Differential Geometry of curves and surface" by do Carmo (2nd edition).
It seems to me that the proof presented in the book is incorrect, so I want to check if I am missing something.

Let me first write down some definitions.

- A subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is called a **regular surface** if it can be covered by parametrizations which will be defined below.
- Let $U$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. A smooth ($C^{\infty}$) map $\mathbf{x} \colon U \to \mathbb{R}^3$ is called a **parametrization** of $S$ if $\mathbf{x}(U) \subset S$, $\mathbf{x}$ is a homeomorphism to its image, and $d\mathbf{x}_q \colon T_qU \to T_{\mathbf{x}(q)}\mathbb{R}^3$ is injective for all $q \in U$.
- $p \in S$ is called **elliptic** if the Gaussian curature at $p$ is positive.

(A part of) **Proposition 1** in Section 3.3 states that all points on $S$ near an elliptic point $p$ lie on the same side of the tangent plane $T_p S$. In the proof of the proposition, the author chooses a parametrization $\mathbf{x} \colon U \to S$ with $\mathbf{x}(0,0) = p$ near an elliptic point $p$ and then uses the Taylor expansion
$$\mathbf{x}(u,v) = \mathbf{x}(0,0) + \mathbf{x}_u u + \mathbf{x}_v v + \frac{1}{2}(\mathbf{x}_{uu}u^2 + 2\mathbf{x}_{uv}uv + \mathbf{x}_{vv}v^2) + \bar{R},$$
where $\bar{R}$ consists of terms of degree $\geq 3$.

However, we can't use the above equation unless we have proved that $\mathbf{x}$ is analytic at $(0,0)$. For instance, if we define $\mathbf{x}(u,v) = \left(u, v, e^{-\frac{1}{u^2+v^2}}\right)$ for $(u,v) \neq (0,0)$ and $\mathbf{x}(0,0) = (0,0,0)$, the map $\mathbf{x}$ is smooth but not analytic at $(0,0)$. The Gaussian curvature at $(0,0,0)$ is zero in this case. So maybe can we say more about elliptic points?

Let me summarize my question.

> Is it always possible to choose an analytic parametrization near an elliptic point?